# Deleting word from line on remote server

Tags: shell, unix, ssh, sed

I am trying to delete a word from bash profile on remote server but the command never come out.

```
ssh -X  test_server  'sed -e \'s/unalias ls//g\' -i .bash_profile' </dev/null
```

Not sure what i am doing wrong, Kindly assist.

Comment: sometimes it's easier (especially nesting quote/double quote) to copy a temporay script file remotely and ssh the script call (and delete it after). Don't forget to specify your environement (with a GNU sed like here it seems linux or mac but no specification on remote, assuming the same)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to nest single quotes in shell, switching to double quotes should give you the desired result. E.g.:

```
$ ssh somehost sh <<< 'echo "Xunalias lsX" | sed -e "s/unalias ls//"'
XX
```

Comment: i tried that as well

sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `"'

Comment: I think I would recommend you copy the file to your machine.  Modify it. Rename the original file.  Copy your new version to the target machine.

Comment: @user3109806 I think you are still trying to escape the double quotes (e.g. `'sed -e \"s/unalias ls//g\"'`)? What you should run instead is `ssh test_server 'sed -e "s/unalias ls//g" -i .bash_profile' </dev/null` which is supposed to work.